# Report during local report processing which have not specified, Path format not support

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winforms, reportviewer

I Have install all package which need for reports viewer but still show have error apply all format path but still face problem.

```
    this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Application.StartupPath + @"C: \Users\nazir\OneDrive\Documents\Nazam pos\Reportproduct.rdlc";
            
    this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
    
    DataSet1 ds = new DataSet1();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    
    cn.Open();
    
    da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("select p.pcode ,p.barcode,p.pdesc,b.brand,c.category,p.purchase,p.price, p.qty, p.reorder  from tblProducts as p inner join tblBrand as b on p.bid=b.id inner join tblCategory as c on p.cid=c.id ", cn);
    da.Fill(ds.Tables["dtproduct"]);
    
    cn.Close();
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTQIG.png)

Image show error

Comment: I'm going out on a limb here and say that, perhaps, you should check the format of the  path string?

Comment: Are you using C++/CLI  or C#? I noticed that there is a space in pah `C:  \Users`.

Comment: C# => i have remove spaces but error not resolve

Answer (score 0):

As @Paulo Santos mentioned, you should check if ReportPath's value is correct, set a breakpoint on the row of the following code and check the value of  ReportPath

```
    this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Application.StartupPath + @"C: \Users\nazir\OneDrive\Documents\Nazam pos\Reportproduct.rdlc";
```

In addition, please modify the code as below and check if it works. mark sure the rdlc file is exist on the fold.

```
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath =  @"C: \Users\nazir\OneDrive\Documents\Nazam pos\Reportproduct.rdlc";
```

Comment: i have already same follow path then show path related error but location different to show error  . I have all package install for rdlc  with extension but no any resolve this error

Comment: It would be better to resolve the issue if you can share a Minimal, Reproducible Example, [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Package version Not integrate with it => Show warning but i have update all package then no should to have resolve it ???

Comment: It is difficult to resolve the issue without a Reproducible Example, I would suggest you could create a new winforms project based the document "[Use the WinForms ReportViewer Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/application-integration/using-the-winforms-reportviewer-control?view=sql-server-ver16)", and then compare the different with that project(including package, configuration file, etc.)

Comment: I have try but again in new projects to do it .